# Params only shows last column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, datatables

I'm using coffe script to generate the javascript code for the datatables, like this:

```
class App.Empresas extends App.Base
inventarios: ->
$ ->
  $('#tabla_inventarios').dataTable
    ajax: $('#tabla_inventarios').data('source')
    columns: [
        data: "id_producto", 
    data: "nombre", 
    data: "categoria"
]
```

but the request using rails log shows this json:

```
 Parameters: {"draw"=>"1", "columns"=>{"0"=>{"data"=>"categoria", "name"=>"", "searchable"=>"true", "orderable"=>"false", "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>"false"}}}, "start"=>"0", "length"=>"10", "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>"false"}, "_"=>"1495682354559", "id"=>"85858-5"}
```

As you can see it only sends 1 column ("categoria") and it should send 3..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing the same key 'data' with different values. To get 3 key-value pair objects, change your code as follows:

```
class App.Empresas extends App.Base
inventarios: ->
$ ->
  $('#tabla_inventarios').dataTable
    ajax: $('#tabla_inventarios').data('source')
    columns: [
        {data: "id_producto"}, 
        {data: "nombre"}, 
        {data: "categoria"}
]
```

or if you want array of strings, do

```
class App.Empresas extends App.Base
inventarios: ->
$ ->
  $('#tabla_inventarios').dataTable
    ajax: $('#tabla_inventarios').data('source')
    columns: [
        "id_producto", 
        "nombre", 
        "categoria"
]
```

Comment: Thanks Sajin, with the second aproach i got: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in id_producto`. But the first one worked... thanks a lot